# What's wrong with this PHP email form script?

Tags: php, syntax

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$reason = $_POST['dropdown'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;

mail("user@example.com", "CWSDesigns Form", "You have received a new message. 
Name: " . $name . " 
From: " . $email . "
Purchasing: " . $reason . "
Message: ". $message .");
?>
```

I get the error message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in /home/u161219738/public_html/contact.php on line 13

I don't know any PHP. I know there errors probably something basic and there are probably other errors in the script.

Comment: Remove the `."` before the last `)`

Comment: You *might* want to remove the e-mail address from the code above so it doesn't get spammed.

Comment: And this is why you don't do multi-line string concatenation. Use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) to define your message string.

Comment: What's wrong? You're passing unescaped external input to the `mail()` function, thus creating a nice little spambot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place variables within a double quoted block, without worry.  Your code had the closing quotes in the wrong place, and your modified code did as well, try this.

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'] ;
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $reason = $_POST['dropdown'] ;
  $message = $_POST['message'] ;

  mail("user@example.com", "CWSDesigns Form", "You have received a new message. 
  Name:  $name  
  From:  $email 
  Purchasing: $reason 
  Message: $message");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The last " is not closed/terminated. You may want to use a editor with proper syntax highlighting to avoid this kind of mistakes! Also be aware to escape/sanatize any possible malicious input from a user.